# use multiple search string to find if value exists?

Tags: arrays, excel, find, vba

I'm trying to go through my excel and find if one of the values found from column, but  can't figure out how it can be done. My goal is to find if any of the filter options exist and if not then do nothing, else go forward with my code. Please can anyone advice on this.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$N$" & i).AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:=Array( _
   "String1", "string2", "string3"), _
   Operator:=xlFilterValues


Set FoundRange = Range("$N$1:$N$" & i).Cells.Find(what:="string1", LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlWhole)

If FoundRange Is Nothing Then
    Cells.AutoFilter
    Exit Sub

Else
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just apply the filter than clear it if it had no effect.

```
Sub ClearAutoFilterIfNoEffect()

    Dim countVisibleRows1 As Long
    Dim countVisibleRows2 As Long
    Dim r As Range

    countVisibleRows1 = WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, Range("$A$1:$N$" & i))

    Range("$A$1:$N$" & i).AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:=Array("String1", "string2", "string3"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

    countVisibleRows2 = WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, Range("$A$1:$N$" & i))

    If countVisibleRows2 = countVisibleRows1 Then
        If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then Cells.AutoFilter
    End If

End Sub
```

Otherwise you'll have to check each condition

```
Sub CheckAllConditionsBeforeApplyingFilter()

    With Range("$A$1:$N$" & i)
        If .Cells.Find(what:="string1", LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
            If .Cells.Find(what:="string2", LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
                If .Cells.Find(what:="string1", LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
                    'Clear the filter if it exists
                    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then Cells.AutoFilter
                    Exit Sub
                Else

                    .AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:=Array("String1", "string2", "string3"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Glad that I could help!